# Convert String to multi-level dictionary keys?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am giving the user the ability to check a specific key in a multi-level dictionary. My idea is that they will pass the path to the key like this:

```
root.subelement1.subelement2.key
```

This can be of arbitrary length and depth.

Once I have the string (above) from the user, I'll split it and get a list of each individual component:

```
elements = ['root', 'subelement1', 'subelement2', 'key']
```

All of this I can do. The next part is where I am stuck. How can I query the dictionary key, specified by the above when it's arbitrary length?

My initial thought was to do something like `my_dict[elements[0]][elements[1]]`...but that doesn't scale or work when my user doesn't pass exactly the length I expect.

How can I get the data at an arbitrary key depth, in this case?

---

A couple examples:

- User passes `country.US.NewYork` => I query `my_dict['country']['US']['NewYork']
- User passes `department.accounting` => I query `my_dict['department']['accounting']`
- User passes `id` => I query `my_dict['id']`
- User passes `district.District15.HenryBristow.principal` => I query `my_dict['district']['District15']['HenryBristow']['principal']`

Comment: I think you'll have to make a loop: `current = my_dict; for bit in query.split('.'): current = current[bit]` plus checks for misses obviously

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you could do that using [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html) which will query the keys in the nested dictionaries:

```
q = "district.District15.HenryBristow.principal"
my_dict  = {"district" : {"District15" : {"HenryBristow" : {"principal" : 12}}}}

from functools import reduce  # python 3 only

print(reduce(lambda x,y : x[y],q.split("."),my_dict))
```

result:

```
12
```

If you want to avoid to catch `KeyError` in case the data doesn't exist with this path, you could use `get` with a default value as empty dictionary:

```
reduce(lambda x,y : x.get(y,{}),q.split("."),my_dict)
```

Trying to get an unknown value returns an empty dictionary. The only drawback is that you don't know from *where* exactly the path got lost, so maybe leaving the `KeyError` be raised wouldn't be so bad:

```
try:
    v = reduce(lambda x,y : x[y],q.split("."),my_dict)
except KeyError as e:
    print("Missing key: {} in path {}".format(e,q))
    v = None
```

Comment: Finally an example of `reduce` that makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Use recursion. Ex:

```
root = {
    'subelement1': {
        'subelement2': {
            'key': 'value'
        }
    }
}

elements = ['subelement1', 'subelement2', 'key']


def getElem(d, keys):
    if keys == []:
        return None
    else:
        key = keys[0]
        remainingKeys = keys[1:]
        if remainingKeys == []:
            return d[key]
        else:
            if type(d[key]) == dict:
                return getElem(d[key], remainingKeys)
            else:
                return None


print(getElem(root, elements))
```

Answer (score 0):

from a python 2.x perspective, you can do this with reduce.

```
query_list = keys.split(":")
print reduce(lambda x,y: x[y], [my_dict] + query_list)
```

But in general, you'll want to do this with a recursive or iterative function if you want to do error handling beyond throwing a `KeyError`.

Answer (score 0):

u can do this like below

```
my_dict = someDict

tmpDict = dict(someDict)   # a coppy of dict
input = "x.u.z"
array = input.split(".")
for key in array:
    tmpDict = tmpDict[key]
print(tmpDict)
```

but your question is **very challenging**:
u say if user send **country.us** then go to `my-dict.country.us`

but what happen if one of this path in my_dict be a **list** code will results error 
u can handle this by check type

```
if isinstance(tmpDict , dict ):
    tmpDict = tmpDict[key]
else:
    # u should say what u want else (a Recursive method u will need)
```

**edit**
if user address maybe wrong you should check `my_dict` have this field or not sample code is below but will be many if i don't like that!
    if key not in tmpDict:
        print("Bad Path")
        return

Answer (score 0):

You can transverse the dictionary using a for loop:

```
s = 'root.subelement1.subelement2.key'
d1 = {'root':{'subelement1':{'subelement2':{'key':15, 'key1':18}}}}
new_d = d1
for key in s.split('.'):
    new_d = new_d[key]

print(new_d)
```

Output:

```
15
```